# Preencher cada value de um input com um caracter de uma variável string

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho uma variável var string = 'TESTE', e pretendo fazer algo do tipo:

```
<input type="text" id="um" value="T">
<input type="text" id="dois" value="E">
<input type="text" id="tres" value="S">
<input type="text" id="quatro" value="T">
<input type="text" id="cinco"value="E">
```

Utilizando javascript, como isso é possível?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma *"div pai"* para inserir seus *inputs* dentro, depois rode um *for* conforme o tamanho da sua *string* e então crie um elemento *input* e use o método [charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) para pegar o caractere daquela posição e inserir como *value*.
O código final ficará assim:

```
var str = 'TESTE';
var div = document.getElementById('div-pai');

for(let i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type = "text";
  input.id = "campo" + (i+1);
  input.value = str.charAt(i);
  div.appendChild(input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Crie um array com os `ids` dos elementos alvo e o itere pelo método [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) com os parâmetros de callback `v` para valor e `i` para o índice do elemento iterado.
Com [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) passando `v` como parâmetro obtenha o respectivo elemento e altere seu valor configurando a propriedade [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#value) com o caractere `i` da string.

```js
let str = "TESTE";

['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco'].forEach(function(v, i) {
  document.getElementById(v).value = (i < str.length) ? str[i] : "";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="um"><br>
<input type="text" id="dois"><br>
<input type="text" id="tres"><br>
<input type="text" id="quatro"><br>
<input type="text" id="cinco"><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Para o primeiro input:**

```
document.getElementById('um').value = string[0]
```

**Segundo input:**

```
document.getElementById('dois').value = string[1]
```

O índice sempre começa com 0, o índice 0 da variável string no caso representa a letra "T" o índice 1 representa a letra "e" e assim sussesivamente é só fazer o mesmo com os outros campos, agora você pode usar isso dentro de um loop for pra ficar de uma forma mais curta e elegante e automatizada, caso você tenha muitos inputs, eu já usaria mesmo nessa quantidade.